# How can Siri recognize a contact's name, but be unable to call that person?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, siri

My wife and I have the same problem with Siri.  In our contacts database, each person has at least one associated phone number (usually associated with 'home', 'mobile' or 'iPhone').  However, even though these numbers are the typical 10 digits used in N. America, Siri frequently will be unable to dial the number despite finding the contact and the number in the database.
Question: can this be fixed without re-entering the numbers to the contacts database? What causes some 10 digit numbers (and numbers with the +1 in front of them) to be unrecognizable for purposes of making Siri-initiated phone calls?

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but for crying out loud, when a text rolls in that comes from a number in the _contacts database_ how hard is it for iOS to swap in the name of that contact instead of the number? The incoming text should be prefaced by the senders *name*!

Comment: Do you have international assist enabled in the Settings -> Phone portion of the settings app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is often a minor activation issue–assuming the iPhone is on Sprint or Verizon. On Verizon, Dial **228* from the Phone app.  On Sprint, dial *##UPDATE#* (##873283#). Follow the voice prompts, if any.  The process takes a minute or two.  After you get a pop-up message indicating the update was successful, wait another minute.  You should see your service indicator go away for a moment then come back.

Afterward, try Siri again. This will likely resolve your text message issues too, though a restart of the iPhone (hold sleep/wake button, swipe to shut off, wait, start back up) may be necessary there.

Comment: woah! Awesome information there - can you share some information on what happens under the hood in this case or a knowledge base article describing the symptoms of this.

Comment: I don't have a formal article to point to. On some occasions the iPhone does not properly load the activation profile, which causes it to format phone numbers incorrectly. This causes Siri, Phone, and the Messages app to be confused about which number goes to which contact. It appears the relevant article "iOS: Troubleshooting received calls or SMS messages not matching" has been pulled, but still shows in Google as TS2326.

Comment: Perfect - that was the link I was looking for. http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2326 - Just hit refresh when you get a 404 from Apple's web servers. They have some problems serving up the knowledge base for some months. :-(

Comment: I'm on Verizon.  I dialed _*228_ and selected their option 2.  After a minute the automated system stated the UPDATE was complete, and I hung up.  I'll report back later whether lingering problems persist.

Comment: The problem seems to have resolved itself. Sorry to be so late with this post. I can only guess, that the above procedure solved the issue.